# FirebaseStorage can't create a downloadURL for metadata

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to use the Firebase Cloud Storage and Realtime Database. In the first one I am uploading an image and then I try to save the downloadUrl in the latter. Everything was working before updating Firebase pod to 5.0.0 for using the MLKit. In StorageService I am uploading the image(which works, I can see it on the firebase console) and then create a dictionary with all my needs, in PostService

```html
struct StorageService {
    static func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, at reference: StorageReference, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
        reference.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                return completion(nil)
            }
            completion(metadata?.downloadURL())
        })
    }
}
```

```html
struct PostService {
    static func create(for image: UIImage) {
        let imageRef = StorageReference.newPostImageReference()
        StorageService.uploadImage(image, at: imageRef) { (downloadURL) in
            guard let downloadURL = downloadURL else {
                return
            }
            print("bum")
            let urlString = downloadURL.absoluteString
            let aspectHeight = image.aspectHeight
            create(forURLString: urlString, aspectHeight: aspectHeight)
        }
    }
    
    private static func create(forURLString urlString: String, aspectHeight: CGFloat) {
        //save the text
        let currentUser = User.current
        let post = Post(imageURL: urlString, imageHeight: aspectHeight)
        let dict = post.dictValue
        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currentUser.uid).childByAutoId()
        postRef.updateChildValues(dict)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a [breaking change](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#5.0.0) in 5.0 of the Firebase iOS SDK that removed the `downloadURL` property on StorageMetadata. Use `StorageReference.downloadURL(completion:)` to obtain a current download URL.

```
reference.downloadURL { url, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also rollback the Firebase version until version 5 is more supported. Though this is a temporary fix.

Add this into your podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 4.0'
```